# Updating database when editing a field in a table

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, database

I have a table, for which the data are pulled from a database and users can edit the data in each cell. So  when user edits a field of the table, how should I update the database? I have to mention for editing, I use `prompt()` method. Should I use ajax? I know my question is so general but I just need some clue.

Updating my question:

This is part of my code: (My table has more cells, the following is just one cell of my table).

```
    while($array=mysql_fetch_array($res))

            {
                <tr>

                <td  >    
                 <center> 
                           <?php 
                                $var=$array['Legacy Data Conversion Required?']; 
                                 if($var) 
                                    echo  
                                    "<p id=$idl>" . $var  .   "</p>" . "<img style ='cursor:pointer; ' class='onInput' src='http://nimbuzz007.hexat.com/icon4/icon%2015.png' id='input_img' onclick='legacyFunction($idl)'>";

                                else 
                                    echo
                                      "<p id=$idl>" . " " . "</p>" . "<img style ='cursor:pointer; ' class='onInput' src='http://nimbuzz007.hexat.com/icon4/icon%2015.png' id='input_img' onclick='legacyFunction($idl)'>"  ;                                           
                            ?> 
                </center> 
            </td>
     </tr>
 }
```

and this is part of the Javascript section:

```
   function legacyFunction($idl) {
var data1 = prompt("Legacy Data Conversion Required?Yes/No");
if (data1 != null) {
    document.getElementById($idl).innerHTML =
    data1;
   }
};
```

So when the user clicks on the edit image there will be a pop up message with input box (I used `prompt()` method), and after user clicks on OK button, the data in the cell of the table will change, but I also need to  update the database. So how can I do that?I mean after what action should I call the ajax function to update the database?

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you could provide your code. How is the table cell being edited? Is it with content edible or a textbox or textarea? Here is my suggestion from the information provided from you. Do this: `<input type="text" oninput="save(this.value);">`

```
function save(textValue)
{
  //put your ajax request here
}
```

If this doesn't work then just tell me and I will try again. Good luck :-) Merry Christmas!

Comment: Triggering a database roundtrip on every keystroke feels bad to me. I would much prefer to trigger it on [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) only.

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a form and set the `action` attribute of that form to your server side file such as *writeToDatabase.php*.  In your form, have all the necessary inputs and fields that you want updated in your database.  You may submit the form via AJAX or simply by a POST/GET method.  Assuming you are using PHP for your server side, establish a connection to your database and update/write the data to the database. Here is more info:

Database connection: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Form Handling: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Updating Data: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp